# How to open a link displayed in Terminal via C Programming?

Tags: c, terminal, esp8266, mbed, teraterm

**My Project:** I am using sensors to gather data and then send it to cloud wirelessly. I have programmed my WiFi module using the AT Instruction Set in C Programming language. As of now, I get the following result in my terminal.

[image]

**My Issue:** As seen in the above screenshot, after my program executes, I get a link which I have to double-click every time in order to push data to cloud.

**My Goal:** To program the code (using C Programming Language) in Online Mbed Compiler so that after getting the **GET https://api......** link, my code will ask the terminal to open the link in the default browser. I am trying to automate the double-clicking part as mentioned before.

What line of code(s) should I add to my C program so that it asks the terminal to open the webpage from the **GET** link that we see in the terminal output as aforementioned?

Thank you for your time and help. I apologies, I do not have much experience with terminal and C coding. So, your help is much appreciated. Thank you very much again!

**EDIT:** Terminal I am using: Tera Term.

I am also open to opening the link that my program gets, to open it directly without relying on the terminal, if opening the link from terminal is not possible. Following is a snippet of my code that generates the GET link:

```
 //Pushing the data acquired from HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor to Cloud Server via API
    sprintf(snd,"GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=3LV9GHWHJYDZNWEH&field1=%f \r\n\r\n", dist_percent);
    pc.printf("%s\r",snd);
    wifi.SendCMD(snd);
    wait(1);
    wifi.RcvReply(rcv, 1000);
    pc.printf("%s\r", rcv);
```

Answer (score -1):

Automating clicks is asking for something to break.  The correct way would be to programmatically follow that link.  Either:

A)  Program an HTTPS stack to connect to the server (I don't actually recommend this outside of a purely academic endeavor)

B)  Learn to use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Thank you for your response, foreverska. I read about curl and thought of using it, but unfortunately, the Online Mbed Compiler from Arm does not have the curl library which I can import in and use it for my program.

Comment: Of course `curl` is not available in Mbed, but you still can do the http request programmatically: https://os.mbed.com/teams/sandbox/code/mbed-http/

Comment: Thank you for the link, Andrejs. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ah, my bad, glossed over the mbed compiler thing.  Good luck.